# Whats the shortcut to Debug in PyDev using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, pydev

The shortcut key is <kbd>F11</kbd> to start debugging. But issue is that I have to be on that file and then hit F11 to start debugging. 
Eg.

my file to launch the application is "`launch.py`" and "`example.py`".
`example.py` is open in the editor  whereas `launch.py` is not.
Now, if I hit <kbd>F11</kbd> it will try to launch the application using "`example.py`" and terminates due to error (as expected).

So then I have to open the "`launch.py`" in the editor and then hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to start debugging the application.
Is there any neater way to configure the debugging, so that it starts the application in single hit/key?

Edit: `example.py` is some other file (some module). It does not launch the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this [PyDev Eclipse Tutorial suggests](http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html):

> After the first run, if you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, the last file ran is re-run. Or, if you type just <kbd>F11</kbd>, a debug session is started with your last run. Let's test this...
>
> Note: This behavior changed in Eclipse 3.3 -- but it's generally recommended to restore it in the preferences at: **`window > preferences > Run/Debug > Launching`** and set the **`Launch Operation`** to **`Always launch the previously launched application`**.
> This tutorial will always consider this as the default option.

[image]

So, did you have this option selected?
If you have launch at least once `launch.py`, then you can re-launch it easily.

Comment: @ssal: especially if your last launch file is "`launch.py`".

Comment: Using mouse :  2 clicks.  and Using keyboard not possible unless I hit F11 on "launch.py".  My eclipse does not have options like the screen shot above. Which version it is? I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web

Comment: @ssal: my point is: if your last launch was on "`launch.py`", then F11 will re-launch "`launch.py`" even if it is not your currently opened file, provided you did select the "`Always launch the previously launched application`" in the "`window > preferences > Run/Debug > Launching`" preference settings.

Comment: ahh .. I did not have the correct preferences set. Cool .. works perfect now .. :) ..thanks VonC

Answer (score 3):

*Although this isn't *strictly* an answer to what was asked initially, it might help someone looking here that had the same problem as me...*

I'm a Java developer mainly, so have the Java view open almost all the time. However, sometimes I want to run some python file to test something (or just create a quick python script, and run it)...

In the Java editor, if the current class has a `main(String[] args)` method, I run it with (and popup the dialog to ask me what exactly I'd like to run in the middle)

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>

Unfortunately, that doesn't work in the Python view, and I've not found a similar solution - it just asks me if I'd like to run it as a Java app... however, as the VonC says, you can run the last run thing (provided you've set the preferences accordingly) with

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd>

and this seems work well with python run configurations too.

*But...* What if the last thing I ran was a Java program, but I now want to run the active `.py` file? Previously, to run the `.py` file, I'd have to go digging through the buttons on the toolbar with the mouse, and I tend to prefer keyboard shortcuts...

**Solution!** So, finally I come to the actual useful bit of this answer - I just discovered by accident (typing Ivan's suggested shortcut, but missing!), it appears that

<kbd>f9</kbd>

will run the currently active python file.

Hope that helps someone get just that little bit faster...

Comment: Yes it seems the preferred way is through F9: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_launch.html

Answer (score 1):

I use CTRL+SHIFT+F9 to relaunch the previous debug configuration in Pydev.