# Is there such a thing as startup file in PyDev under Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have created a new project in Eclipse, PyDev.

If I were in VS2010, I would mark a project as startup project, and whenever I click F5, it runs.

I want to mark one .py file to be my so called **Main**, and that each time I click run (F11), it will be the one to run, and not the current that is being edited.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `run -> run configurations`

In the menu on the right you should have `Python Run` option. Create new run configuration by double clicking.

On the right you can select the project you want to run and it's main module. The other tabs can be used to configure arguments, python interpreter used to run the project, etc..

Comment: Thank a lot! How can I assign a shortcut that whenever I press some key, a specific run configuration is used?

Comment: Ok, I have found the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721444/whats-the-shortcut-to-debug-in-pydev-using-eclipse

Comment: @Andrey sorry for late reply, glad you managed to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @soulcheck, I have found the problem.
It seems that the problem is that Eclipse 3 tries to launch current file instead of the main.

Here is the solution:
[Whats the shortcut to Debug in PyDev using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721444/whats-the-shortcut-to-debug-in-pydev-using-eclipse)