# Pydev wine pythonpath issues/console initialization timeout issue

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pythonpath, wine

I've set up an interpreter in Pydev that calls a small script:

```
#!/bin/bash
WINEDEBUG=fixme-all WINEPREFIX=/home/dal/wine/Python wine C:\\Python27\\python.exe "$@"
```

to fire up an instance of the windows version of python (which I need in order to get to windows-only ODBC database drivers).
This much works fine, I am able to start a console, run scripts using that interpreter etc.

However - I now need to add a reference to a directory storing a bunch of modules that I need to access - however the windows version of python wants a PYTHONPATH that has elements separated by semicolons and in Z:\home\blah\whatever format, rather that colons and /home/blah/whatever.

Pydev won't let me add arbitrary paths in the preferences -> pydev -> interpreters -> libraries section (it wants me to find the path in a file picker, then creates a /home/blah/whatever string from what was picked).

Attempting to use the enviroment tab to set PYTHONPATH to ${PYTHONPATH}\;Z:\path\I\need results in pydev telling me to forget about it (it won't let me set PYTHONPATH specifically from that dialog).

Adding `PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}\;Z:\\path\\I\\need` to the shell script which calls the windows version of python via wine was the last thing I could think of, but it causes something bad to happen in pydev:

```
Error initializing console.
Unexpected error connecting to console.
Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg  received: Failed to read server's response: Connection refused
```

yup, it fails to recive.

I can manually:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'Z:\really\long\path\that\I\dont\want\to\type\often')
```

and things will work, but...I'd really like to not have to type that each time.

putting the above in a file and pointing the PYTHONSTARTUP environmental variable at it solves that problem for a python instance running from the terminal, but the python instance running inside pydev doesn't seem to look at PYTHONSTARTUP at all

Gone through just about all the ideas I can come up with at this time of night (short of simply importing the whole modules directory into every project I work on in pydev, which seems...inelegant, to say the least), does anyone else have a thought on how to push this particular square peg through the round hole?

Update: the module directory is actually mounted via sshfs, and with it in the pythonpath, launching an instance of the python interpreter from a terminal is somewhat slow (35sec ish). Attempting to launch a console from within pydev appears to time out in < 15sec, so I'm wondering if what's needed here is just some way to increase the amount of time it waits for a response from the interpreter it's trying to launch before giving up, and if the 'connection refused' message at the end of the output snippet means (as the rest of that snippet seems to suggest) 'connection not accepted before I gave up' more so than 'interpreter told me explicitly connection was not going to happen'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try playing around with `sys.path`

```
import sys
print sys.path #  print a list of locations Python searches for modules
sys.path.append('Z:\\path\\I\\need')

# now import your modules
import my_module
```

Regarding your `PYTHONPATH` method, you could also try putting into single quotes - your current method doesn't escape properly, and `\\n` is interpreted as a newline character.

```
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}\;'Z:\\path\\I\\need'
```

Comment: Works, but the plan was to avoid having to do that each time I open a console :/

Comment: Updated answer regarding your `PYTHONPATH` attempt

Comment: Path was just an example, actual path components start with h, d, s, c, and p - don't *think* any of them would get turned into a path breaking char like \\n -> \n. Have also actually been using r'Z:\some\path' to save wear and tear on \ for a bit - I'll update the original question to reflect that

Comment: Have you looked here regarding your PYTHONSTARTUP problem? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8688355/276949 . Also `\c` is turned into a path breaking character, so you would still want to escape your string for `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: PYTHONSTARTUP within pydev's run configuration dialogue unfortunately appears to be ignored just like the global per-interpreter setting. The other question linked is about someone wanting to rerun a specific module everytime f11 is pressed irrespective of what is open in the current editor window, not someone wanting a piece of code/separate file run prior to execution of whatever f11 causes to run. quoting the Z:\ path gives the same result, although I'm wondering whether that might be a timeout issue not explicit problem now - will update my question above.

Comment: Thinking that the new issue (console initialization timeout - assuming that's what is stopping the PYTHONPATH addition to the shell script from solving the problem) is probably distinct enough from the original issue to warrant a separate question, and that the info here does solve the original issue - so I'm calling the original question solved and starting a new one re: console initialization timeout.